# @EnableOAuth2Sso AND @EnableResourceServer in same app

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I'd like have a set of services that can be used with "Client Credential" (for machine to machine) and with OAuth2 Single Sign On for the regular webapp (which is served by the same application).

I tried setting both @EnableOAuth2Sso and @EnableResourceServer; I expected to have the app "try" the token based and then fall back to SSO redirect in case it doesn't find any and the user does not have a session.

Each config works fine on its own (with a:

`@Bean
 public RemoteTokenServices ...`

for @EnableResourceServer to configure the "CheckTokenEndpointUrl").

But as soon as I try with both I get:

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - userInfoTokenServices: defined by method 'userInfoTokenServices' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$UserInfoTokenServicesConfiguration.class]
    - remoteTokenServices: defined by method 'remoteTokenServices' in class path resource [my/CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class]

Comment: I have the same issue, can you please share the solution if u found?

Answer (score 0):

In your spring boot application class use the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation and in the configuration class use `@EnableResourceServer` annotation and in this class define the endpoints to be used with access tokens.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer 
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .antMatcher("/user")  //end point that needs access token in header
      .antMatcher("/info")  //end point that needs access token in header
      .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
}
```

For more information refer the [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)